# c# prevent unnecessary api calls

Tags: c#, ienumerable, api-design

I have an api that fetches data in pages and send it back to the client. If a client iterates over the returned collection more than once i want to prevent additional calls to the api

```
var actualItems = _pagedApiCollection.GetItems<Foo>().ToArray();
```

Call to api

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetItems<Foo>() {
  Page currentPage;
  do
  {
    currentPage =  _pagedApi.GetNextPage(reqid);

    foreach (var item in currentPage)
        yield return (Foo)item;

  } while (currentpage.HasNextPage);
}
```

IE how can additional calls to

```
_pagedApiCollection.GetItems<Foo>().ToArray()
```

Be prevented from new page fetches? Is it possible to Cache results in a property until Dispose() or similar?

Comment: Just reuse `actualItems` or cache that array. If you use dotnet core you can use dependency injection to set up an IMemoryCache for each controller

Comment: Thanks @JoePhillips, I dont have control over how _pagedApiCollection.GetItems<Foo>().ToArray() will be used by the client so ineed shomething inside Getitems() to chache the results

Comment: it's all the same. Just cache it inside of there then. I'm not sure what you're really asking. Sounds like you already know what to do